R: Find all variables with non-dominated means and variances FAST
I have a set of many random variables, each with a mean and standard deviation.  I want to find all variables that are or are not dominated, i.e., that have the highest mean for their standard deviations.  In other words, if X1 has a mean of 10 and and an sd of 10, and X2 has a mean of 9 and an sd of 11, then X2 is dominated by X1.  Essentially, I will want to discard it.  This is a common problem in portfolio optimization.
Easy when speed is not a concern:

aredominated1 <- function( smean, svar ) {
    PN <- length(smean)
    kill <- rep(FALSE, PN)

    for (i in 1:PN) {
        for (j in 1:PN) {
            if (i==j) next
            kill[i] <- if ((smean[i] < smean[j]) & (svar[i] > svar[j])) 1 else kill[i]
            if (kill[i]) break  ## no longer any need to check whether i is dominated by a subsequent j
        }
    }

    kill
}


aredominated2 <- function( smean, svar ) {
    PN <- length(smean)
    kill <- rep(FALSE, PN)

    for (i in 1:PN) {
        kill[i] <- any( (smean[i] < smean) & (svar[i] > svar) )
    }
    kill
}


####

T <- 100000
smean <- rnorm(T)
svar <- abs(rnorm(T))

print( system.time( { v1 <- aredominated1( smean, svar ) } ) )
print( system.time( { v2 <- aredominated2( smean, svar ) } ) )
            
stopifnot( all( v1 == v2 ) )



Roughly speaking, aredominated1 takes 1.5 secs, while aredominated2 (more R-like) takes 60 secs.  Is there a much faster way to write such a function in R, or am I close to the native R limit here?

Maybe you can optimize the loop like below
tic <- function(smean, svar) {
    k <- order(smean)
    v <- svar[k]
    l <- length(v)
    kill <- vector(length = l)
    for (i in 1:(l - 1)) {
        for (j in (i + 1):l) {
            if (v[i] > v[j]) {
                kill[i] <- 1
                break
            }
        }
    }
    kill[order(k)]
}

Benchmark
ivo1 <- function(smean, svar) {
    PN <- length(smean)
    kill <- rep(FALSE, PN)

    for (i in 1:PN) {
        for (j in 1:PN) {
            if (i == j) next
            kill[i] <- if ((smean[i] < smean[j]) & (svar[i] > svar[j])) 1 else kill[i]
            if (kill[i]) break ## no longer any need to check whether i is dominated by a subsequent j
        }
    }

    kill
}

ivo2 <- function(smean, svar) {
    PN <- length(smean)
    kill <- rep(FALSE, PN)

    for (i in 1:PN) {
        kill[i] <- any((smean[i] < smean) & (svar[i] > svar))
    }
    +kill
}

tic <- function(smean, svar) {
    k <- order(smean)
    v <- svar[k]
    l <- length(v)
    kill <- vector(length = l)
    for (i in 1:(l - 1)) {
        for (j in (i + 1):l) {
            if (v[i] > v[j]) {
                kill[i] <- 1
                break
            }
        }
    }
    kill[order(k)]
}

sbaldur <- function(smean, svar) {
    dt <- data.table(smean, svar)[, row := .I]
    setorder(dt, -smean, svar)
    dt[, kill := as.numeric(svar > cummin(svar))]
    dt$kill[order(dt$row)]
}



microbenchmark(
    ivo1 = ivo1(smean, svar),
    ivo2 = ivo2(smean, svar),
    tic = tic(smean, svar),
    sbaldur = sbaldur(smean, svar),
    times = 10,
    check = "equal",
    unit = "relative"
)

shows
Unit: relative
    expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq         max
    ivo1  22.371324  19.695451  17.558189  18.104484  18.385273  11.2895773
    ivo2 439.136523 390.277007 340.305299 355.019021 333.328700 220.5935180
     tic   1.562904   1.397621   1.255117   1.340289   1.262332   0.7891665
 sbaldur   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.0000000
 neval
    10
    10
    10
    10


zee sbaldur function is pretty incredible...

Your current algorithm is O(n^2). You could move to O(n log(n)) by sorting the data first.
library(data.table)
aredominated1_dt <- function(smean, svar) {
  dt <- data.table(smean, svar)[, row := .I]
  setorder(dt, -smean, svar)
  dt[, kill := as.numeric(svar > cummin(svar))]
  dt$kill[order(dt$row)]
}

data.table is not strictly necessary here. The logic can easily be translated to base R or dplyr (but if performance is critical I would make comparisons with collapse).
Benchmarks:
T <- 100000
smean <- rnorm(T)
svar <- abs(rnorm(T))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  aredominated1_dt(smean, svar),
  aredominated1(smean, svar),
  check = "identical",
  times = 3
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                           expr       min        lq      mean    median
#  aredominated1_dt(smean, svar)   24.8443   24.8443   24.8443   24.8443
#     aredominated1(smean, svar) 1801.3821 1801.3821 1801.3821 1801.3821

And to get an idea of the scaling we quadruple the input (T <- 400000)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                           expr       min        lq      mean    median
#  aredominated1_dt(smean, svar)   60.3873   60.3873   60.3873   60.3873
#     aredominated1(smean, svar) 9213.9352 9213.9352 9213.9352 9213.9352


Your first method is fast because you are not testing every possiblility.
You can reduce the computation time even more (by more than half) by only testing the "svar" part conditional on the first part being TRUE, using && instead of & and omitting the if.
aredominated3 <- function( smean, svar ) {
  PN <- length(smean)
  kill <- rep(FALSE, PN)
  
  for (i in 1:PN) {
    for (j in 1:PN) {
      if (i==j) next

      ## modify this line
      kill[i] <- smean[i] < smean[j] && svar[i] > svar[j]

      if (kill[i]) break  ## no longer any need to check 
    }
  }
  
  kill
}

print( system.time( { v1 <- aredominated1( smean, svar ) } ) )
   #user  system elapsed 
   #2.66    0.00    3.02 

print( system.time( { v3 <- aredominated3( smean, svar ) } ) )
   #user  system elapsed 
   #0.85    0.00    0.92 

stopifnot( all( v1 == v3 ) )

